# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) . DB_HOST set to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I moved the Laravel project from localhost to server. Which I have done every step on the server.

I am able to view the login page on my server. The problem is I am not able to connect with my MySQL server.

My `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Transport
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:mrakeyidharhaikonsdf
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=transport_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

I tried to change the host to `127.0.0.1` and also tried to put my server's IP address. It didn't helped me. Am I missing something?

My error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = user.email@gmail.com)

<sub>I know this question may have answers already on Stack Overflow. But I have different issue here.</sub>

Comment: have you cached configuration after updating db settings?

Comment: I did . !! using `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: after changed anything in the `.env` file,run `php artisan config:cache` command.

Comment: Your password is not used.

Comment: I have another password , I just edited for convenience

Comment: Check in database.php whether env variables are used or not

Comment: @Rahul I checked and verified,  Even tried to add manually in `database.php`  , didn't help

Comment: can you manually connect to mysql from server terminal?

Comment: I can able to connect with it using mysql -u root -p . And also tested with index.php using basic php connection using https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp . It works

Comment: Can you try `php artisan config:clear` and retry your action?

Comment: I did . No use ~

Comment: How are you testing the connection? Are you running `php artisan tinker` ? Or are you running a url?

Comment: bootstrap/cache/config.php remove this file. then fire php artisan config:cache. then check again

Comment: @RobBiermann I already have users table in db and tried to run `php artisan migrate` . It also throws the same error

Comment: @Rahul no such file in that folder

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running this command from the correct directory? Are you on the root of your project?(sometimes people have multiple laravel folders next to each other)

Comment: Do you have bootstrap folder or not? Inside that do you have cache folder? No? Then fire composer update. And artisan command should be fired from root folder.

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes . I'm running those commands from eact folder

Comment: @Rahul inside `bootstrap/cache` there are only two files . `packages.php` and `services.php`

Comment: Something is wrong then. I am too working on L6. I have config.php file.

Comment: *"I moved the laravel project from localhost to server"* To what server do you deploy or try to run your app..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have a server which has ssh access . So I pushed all my codes to github then got it to server using git clone command . Then Composer update and some other changes

Comment: *"I have a server which has ssh access"* dedicated or something like docker?

Comment: @RaymondNijland dedicated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure your database credentials and database host are set correctly:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="your_database_name"
DB_USERNAME="put_db_user_name _here"
DB_PASSWORD="put_db_password_here_if_have_set"
```

If you have not set any database password then add:

```
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

Comment: Have you tried to change DB_HOST=localhost to DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I did . Also tried to put the IP address. Didn't help

Comment: Once you should try to put into double quotes like 

DB_USERNAME="db_user_name"
DB_PASSWORD="db_password"

Then

php artisan cache:clear

Comment: That is insane . I missed to put my `DB_PASSWORD = "db_password" `.

Comment: Single Quotes for DB_PASSWORD worked for me after spending 5 hours to figure out the issue. `DB_PASSWORD = 'mydb_password'`

Answer (score 38):

To be honest, while working on Laravel 6, I also faced this issue many times and probably was unable to figure out the solution. I tried commands like
`php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`, but these two commands didn't help.

To come over this issue, you have to execute all the below commands:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Note: Make sure in `.env` you have add `db_password` and it is not null and also check if your `db_password` uses any special character. Always enclose them in `""`.

Example:

```
DB_PASSWORD="%123456%"
```

To debug this issue you can also create a test route and then dump the `.env` variable there to check if they have the correct values or not.

```
Route::get('/test/env', function () {
    dd(env('DB_DATABASE')); // Dump 'db' variable value one by one
});
```

**Note: Please make sure to restart your server.**

Comment: Arey yar . Check all those comments. I did everything . When I'm running `php artisan optimize`  I'm getting the same error .                                          PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Comment: try accessing your `.env variable` in your controller and dump its value what are you getting?

Comment: @farooq i've updated my answer check now and post what are you getting?

Comment: `transport`  which is db name .

Comment: also try to access your db_user and db_password to make sure your application is loading .env correctly

Comment: Lol. Thanks man . I figured it out because of both answers. I missed a part where that's my problem :) . I missed to put the password inside ""

Comment: Glad you fixed it happy to help. ;)

Comment: Now, I'm getting confused , which one should I mark it as fixed?

Comment: Which helped you the most ;)

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks

Comment: I was not having the SSH access in the shared hosting cPanel account. But when I put the password in "double quotes". It worked :-)

Comment: Enclosing password in double quotes fixed my issue. Nice.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the project made a cache file. 'config.php' must be deleted in order to allow the system to restart and you can do so by locate this file and deleting it:

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working in the Laravel framework using homestead and had such a problem. In fact, this error was because I did not create the database in [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29). So, I created the database. In more details:

1. run `vagrant ssh` to get homestead command line.
2. run `mysql` to start the MySQL command line client.
3. run `create database database_name;` to create your database. Note that the database should be inside two ` (*not* ') marks.
4. Modify the *.env* file of the Laravel project as below:

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=askidb2
   DB_USERNAME=homestead
   DB_PASSWORD=secret
   ```
5. (if you previously made your model and configured files in Laravel projects for creation tables), run `php artisan migrate` in the command line of the project's folder. This causes it to create tables in the askidb2 database.
6. (perhaps optional for you) since before I set needed files for seeding the question table I just run `php artisan db:seed` to seed my desired table(s).

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Homestead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestead_Technologies) to serve your application, you must connect to the Homestead built-in database. Otherwise, I get an error (*SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'*) when I try to connect to the MySQL database that is installed on my Mac.

Here is how I connect to the Homestead database. I am not sure why the host → 127.0.0.1 from the Laravel documentation doesn't work.

**In the .env file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I use Sequel Pro as the GUI to manage the database, and here is how I connect Sequel Pro to the Homestead MySQL database.

**Connect with standard mode**

Host: 192.168.10.10 
User: homestead 
Password: secret 
Port: 3306

**Connect with SSH mode**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is mine. I apologize for that.

I missed to put my `DB_PASSWROD` inside `""`. So that caused my two hours.

I have the password which contains some special characters at the beginning. So it should be inside the `""` to avoid the problems.

For example, if my password is `"%helloworld@"`,
then in the `.env` file, it should be:

```
`DB_PASSWORD="%helloworld@" `
```

Previously, I had

```
`DB_PASSWORD=%helloworld@
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error while my connection with the database was established. The problem was that I was on *localhost*, not 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
DB_DATABASE="your_database_name"
DB_USERNAME="put_db_user_name _here"
DB_PASSWORD="put_db_password_here_if_have_set"
```

Then type

```
php artisan config:clear
```

This will make your problem clear. Then type

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because my XAMPP user Account access for root and password did not match Laravel .env database DB_USERNAME & DB_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 0):

This will Work:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="your_database_name"
DB_USERNAME="put_db_user_name _here"
DB_PASSWORD="put_db_password_here_if_have_set"
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also be due to the **DB_PORT**. Go to the PhpMyAdmin Database server and check the server.
So I changed from this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.env` as follows

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="Your DB name"
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and then run `php artisan config:cache`

and then run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

and then run `php artisan serve`

Please make sure to have the same db name in `.env` file and db name in `php myadmin`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your mysql port no as well.
If you have changed your xampp mysql port, then do check PORT Number in your projectfolder ".env" file as well as "database.php" file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs another solution:

> 1.- Connect to mysql workbench
>
> 2.- Create the database

*Check the connection using:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your laravel application can not connect to your database connection
check and troubleshoot these following issues:

1. Check mysql server status at first it means mysql server running or not and accessing to it
2. Make sure mysql credential is correct or not, you can check for example with sequel pro or navicat or other free softwares
3. check database permissions, this user have GRANT permission to access to this DB
4. Clear laravel cache with this command

> `php artisan cache::clear`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, if I have Bitnami WordPress. It's a service using an Apache/localhost address, so my [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) instance is only accessible via 127.0.0.1 and when accessing localhost I got 'Access denied error ...'. Then when I stop the Bitnami service, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

my mistake is i configure .env.example

you must configure .env file

Comment: There is clearly an `.env` file in the question, so this cannot be an answer to this question.  Please attempt to answer the *question* that asked, not the *title*. Thanks!