# PHP - Problem with PDO / mysqli connection over VPN

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, vpn

I'm trying to create a connection to a local Database Server through a VPN connection first.

From the VPN connection I receive this IP for my network:
**192.168.30.2**

DB-Server:
**192.168.40.150**

If I try to ping the DB Server IP via PHP, I also get a response from the Server. When, however, I try to make the PDO connection or with "mysqli", I receive the following error:

```
lluminate \ Database \ QueryException: SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'192.168.30.2' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `xxxx`) in file
```

If I use a Mysql Client from my PC it's working fine!

Any idea?

Comment: does the user in mysql accept connection from 192.168.30.2 ? ('xxxx'@'%') ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813485/12232340 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234430/12232340

Comment: @SmasherHell if I use a mysql client software on my local machine works fine. IP is: 192.168.30.2

Comment: @Dlk configuration seems OK. I tried to debug the PDO Connection and the Host is: 192.168.40.150. I dont understand because the PDO Connectore use the IP Address from VPN ('xxxx'@'192.168.30.2')

Comment: I am not laravel person. but that sounds like you need to include port into connection  ?

Comment: From what you tell, there is only two causes : the mysql user does not accept your host, but if your other client work fine locally, I think you may have a typo in your user/password. The message from the server is clearly "I can not authenticate you"

Comment: FOUND: SSL Connection was required!
These PDO options are needed: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => ''

Other Problem: my Laravel "database.php" config doesn't read these options.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**: the DB server required a SSL Connection (without Cert). These options was required in the PDO connection:

- `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`
- `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA`

If you use Laravel Illuminate for the connection you need to declerate the options in the connection, example:

```
...
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => env('MY_SSL_VERIFY', ' '),
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MY_SSL_CA', ' '),
        ]) : [],
...
```

In this case is really important to give a Value with empty space `' '` otherwise will the Illuminate PDO Connector not get the option values.