# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied , using aws EC2 ubuntu

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I done,

- **Connect mysql** in terminal by **root** user which has **grant access**.
- Run **php artisan cache:clear** && **php artisan config:cache**.
- Created another user & give Grant access.
- Connect SQLyog via SSH (using PEM file) & also create db & tables there.
- env file multiple times check and typos also.

Still I can not able to receive success response from my API url.

my env files variable

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=my_secret_pw
```

**Please suggest me, what's the issue or missing something ?**

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this. When I found this question *[SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) . DB_HOST set to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233866/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)*

I have a same situation but didn't find this earlier.

Really thanks to all of them who contribute in above question.

"" (Double Quotes) matter, very!!!