# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using MAMP in the macOs. I was download the laravel 5 from cpanel. I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `products` where `pro_status` = 1 and `pro_stock` > 0 order by `pro_id` desc limit 8)
```

But can't fix it.

Comment: enc file use quote for password  if you have spcial character. DB_PASSWORD="sfsa"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) . DB\_HOST set to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233866/sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password)

Answer (score 0):

Just set 'password'. That solved my problem.